# Artifacts after applying subdivison surface modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface, artifacts

I get strange artifacts after applying subdivison surface modifier. There are no double vertices. The problem is only in this place. The rest is nice. How can I fix it?

Without subdivision:

[image]

With subdivision:

[image]

Wire view with crease values:
[image]

And with subdivision:
[image]

Comment: Check out the crease value (1) in the n-panel for all the edges around the vertex.

Comment: you need to change the topology, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Please, see the additional screenshots. Thank you!

Comment: @AM: the "mean crease" is 0 as can be seen on the picture... does it gives you any ideas?